# Chief factor of a group and what are its types?

Tags: group-theory, book-recommendation, quotient-group, frattini-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group. A section $H/K$ where $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $K\leq H$ called a chief factor if $H/K$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/K$. What are the possible types of chief factors?

I've read somewhere a complemented chief factor of $G$ can't be a Frattini chief factor of $G$. How?
Prove or disprove Frattini chief factor of $G$ always abelian?

It's a very new topic to me, so I want to read about chief factors and their properties thoroughly. Can anyone suggest some good books/links to understand this concept.

Comment: If $H/K$ has a complement $C/K$ then, at least when $G/K$ is finite, $C/K$ is contained in a maximal subgroup $M/K$ of $G/K$, and $M/K$ does not contain $H/K$, so $H/K \not\le \Phi(G/K)$. I have not thought about the infinite case.

Comment: Okay. In the question, $H/K$ is a complemented chief factor of group $G$, that means $H/K$ has a complement in $G/K$, right? Then we can connect it to the Frattini subgroup of $G/K$.

Comment: The Frattini subgroup of a finite group is nilpotent, so yes a Frattini chief factor must be abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt. For the finite case, I agree that the Frattini chief factors are abelian. Any hint for the infinite case?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to solve these problems for infinite Frattini chief factors.